# How to apply style to a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, class, html, height

I have multiple divs in my body which need the same style:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

I have a javascript that calculates the height of the browser window viewport height.
I want to apply that height to all my "box" classed divs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
var height = (window.innerHeight) ? window.innerHeight: document.documentElement.clientHeight;
box.style.height=(height)+'px';
</script>
```

This works, but only with one div, it doesn't make the second "box" div the same height as the previous. If I change the number in square brackets from 0 to 1 it applies the height to the second div. Also, if I make a second copy of the javascript so that the first script has [0] and the second [1] it applies the height to both divs. I can't delete the square brackets because then the javascript doesn't work at all. I have also tried to get the name with getElementsByTagName with no success.

How can I make this javascript apply the same height to all the divs with "box" class? Or is there another way to do what I try to do?

Comment: 0 is the index of the first element of the array returned by `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the following:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('box'),
    size = elems.length;

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {

var box = elems[i];
var height = (window.innerHeight) ? window.innerHeight: document.documentElement.clientHeight;
box.style.height=(height)+'px';
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JRdHD/

Comment: Just a crazy thought, but try and store `document.getElementsByClassName` in a variable and iterate over it. So that, you know, you won't have to walk the entire DOM tree every loop iteration,

Comment: i would think it would be advisable to eliminate the repetitive DOM references, no?  I think one variable to store the nodelist from getElementsByClassName, and then loop through that.  every little bit helps.

Comment: Except that *getElementsByClassName* is not supported by all browsers, so a feature test is required with an alternative.

Comment: If you wanted backwards compatibility that badly, you can loop the whole document once and store matches in an array. If the browser is modern, you can just branch and return getElementsByClassName. (Oh, this post is almost 9 years old. That explains the need for backwards compatibility.)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to document.write the style in the html,
while the page is being read, after the link elements are defined.

```
<script>
document.writeln('<style>div.box{height:'+
document.documentElement.clientHeight+'px;}'+
'<\/style>');
</script>
</head>

<body...
```